# Team Foundation Server (TFS) "My alerts" doesn't exist after configuring SMTP server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We followed these guides in an attempt to turn on email/text alerts for TFS work items when they are updated or changed:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181334.aspx

FTA: From a web browser, connect to your team project and open alerts management (My alerts from your profile menu). If you don't see this option, then you must configure an SMTP server to support TFS.

We didn't see the option, so we followed the guide to set up a smtp server using this guide here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400808.aspx

FTA: To verify your configuration, open alerts management. You might need to refresh your browser to see this option if you just recently enabled an SMTP server.

We've sent a successful test email through the administration area but we can't verify because the users are not seeing the "My Alerts" option to set up their own alerts in the online portals.

Is there something else we need to do that is not included in the guide to set these up?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the following URL on your TFS server: https://nakedalm.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Democorp/_admin/_alerts (replacing the server with yours) you should see your Alerts